# oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database. Connection failed with "[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE]

Tags: python, oracle, cx-oracle, python-oracledb

when I try to connect with oracle database with oracledb a python module I'm getting this error.

```
oracledb.exceptions.OperationalError: DPY-6005: cannot connect to database. Connection failed with "[SSL: SSLV3_ALERT_HANDSHAKE_FAILURE] sslv3 alert handshake failure (_ssl.c:997)
```

I'm using python 3.10.6 version.

and my code is like this

```
cs = "(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS_LIST = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCPS)(HOST = hostname)(PORT = 1533)))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVICE_NAME = service name)))"
c = oracledb.connect(user='username', password="password", dsn=cs)
cur=c.cursor()
```

when I'm using with normal method like this

```
connection = oracledb.connect(user="hr", password=userpwd,
                                  dsn="dbhost.example.com:1984/orclpdb")
```

I'm getting error like this

```
oracledb.exceptions.DatabaseError: DPY-4011: the database or network closed the connection
```

I want use this connection in my Django app to access data from oracle server. I'm kinda new to this oracle can anyone help me please with this.

Comment: Did you configure your sqlnet connection properly for tcps (server side and client side). Have a look [here](https://oracle-base.com/articles/misc/configure-tcpip-with-ssl-and-tls-for-database-connections) for an example

Comment: that error suggests that you are using mTLS and require a client certificate and private key (aka wallet), as shown in the link provided by @gsalem. For thin mode, you can follow the instructions for mTLS for cloud databases: https://python-oracledb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html#mutual-tls-mtls-connection-to-oracle-autonomous-database